# Clear BehaviorSubject of queued events as each is addressed in Angular2 with Observables

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, rxjs, angular2-observables

I'm having a problem that I'm sure is entirely based on my (lack of) a complete understanding of Observables.

This is an Angular2 (v4.0.3) project using rx/js and Observables.

I have a state store that holds events in a state service:

```
  // Observable string sources
  private currentEventStore = new BehaviorSubject<string>("");

  // Observable string streams
  public currentEvent$ = this.currentEventStore.asObservable();

  // Service message commands
  setCurrentEvent(nextEvent: string) {
    this.currentEventStore.next(nextEvent);
  }
```

I subscribe to currentEvent$ in my components to listen for events, and then act on them.

```
this.stateSvc.currentEvent$
  .subscribe(
  currentEvent => {
    this.currentEvent = currentEvent;
    if (currentEvent != '') {
      this.handleCurrentEvent(currentEvent);
    }
  });
```

The problem I'm having is that the store is accumulating all events and returning all of them each time, so that when I spawn a 'create' event, my subscribed function picks up the event and creates a record - perfect on the first pass, but if I spawn a second 'create' event, my subscribed function picks up 2 events, and creates 2 records, and on the next 'create' event it creates 3 records, and so on.

What I need to happen is for the event to be flushed out of the stream so that the currentEvent$ store only holds events that haven't been addressed.

Is there a way to flush the store? Or is there something I'm missing here in my expectations and implementation?

Comment: The only thing `BehaviorSubject` does is that it has a default value that is sent on subscription to each observer (that's what `ReplaySubject` does.). It doesn't store values going through so the problem is somewhere else and not in using `BehaviorSubject`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As is often the case, after days of banging my head against a problem, within hours of posting a question I work out the answer.

The issue here is that every time I revisit the component that registers the subscriber, it adds a new subscriber to the observable, so that on the second visit, there are two subscribers, and each fires, resulting in the event being handled twice. Come back a third time, and there are now three subscribers, so the event gets handled three times.

What I need to do is modify my subscriptions so that they are assigned to a variable, and then when destroying the component, I unsubscribe.

So the subscribe should look like this (note the addition of **'this.observeEvent ='**:

```
this.observeEvent = this.stateSvc.currentEvent$
  .subscribe(
  currentEvent => {
    this.currentEvent = currentEvent;
    if (currentEvent != '') {
      this.handleCurrentEvent(currentEvent);
    }
  });
```

And I add this to the component:

```
ngOnDestroy() {
  this.observeEvent.unsubscribe();
}
```

Which unregistered the subscriber so they don't accumulate each time this component loads.

I had tried to figure out how to accomplish this earlier, but without assigning the Observable to an instance variable, I couldn't find any valid syntax to unsubscribe in the ngOnDestroy method.